# JSP...tables for multiple objects

Tags: jsp

In JSP,The requirement is to create a history page which will show history of any kind of object like order,customer,payment,shipping.

How to create tables for multiple objects wihtout using IF on object type?

Thank You.

Comment: What problem are you facing, what do you want to achieve, what have you tried and can you also post some code?

Comment: use the [command design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you should introduce a generalization on the model side: Maybe an Interface declaring all getters you need for history display. With all your order, customer, payment and shipping classes implementing that Interface, you can rely on the getters being accessible from the JSP.